# How to post html multipart form data using PHP cURL

Tags: php, html, post, curl

Please help me to post the following multipart form data using PHP cURL

```
url = "http://smssheep.com/sendsms.php";
reffer="http://smssheep.com/";

POSTDATA =-----------------------------187161971819895
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="country"

0091
-----------------------------187161971819895
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="no"

00918714349616
-----------------------------187161971819895
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="msg"

hggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
-----------------------------187161971819895
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x_form_secret"

bqu9hv488bxu
-----------------------------187161971819895
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="saveForm"

SEND
-----------------------------187161971819895
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="comment"


-----------------------------187161971819895
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="idstamp"

Ds11xxs27YzNm/r/vf I rmQbz2TS1yaMNXeuHD6ozI=
-----------------------------187161971819895--
```

Any help will be a great help.

Comment: Does it have to be multipart though? Either multipart or application/x-www-form-urlencoded should work in the same way.

Comment: Please have a look [here](http://scraperblog.blogspot.com/2013/07/php-curl-multipart-form-posting.html)

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS
```

Answer (score 1):

It works exactly like [explained in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/function.curl-setopt.php):

```
$data = 'url = "http://smssheep.com/sendsms.php";
reffer="http://smssheep.com/";

POSTDATA =-----------------------------187161971819895
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="country"

...

Ds11xxs27YzNm/r/vf I rmQbz2TS1yaMNXeuHD6ozI=
-----------------------------187161971819895--'

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

Comment: this example is incomplete/wrong as you must pass in a hash array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS for it to become a multi-part formpost

Comment: @DanielStenberg: No, if you have it pre-formatted like in this example, this is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
$url = "http://smssheep.com/sendsms.php";
$reffer="http://smssheep.com/";
$data = array(
        'country' => '0091',
        'no' => '00918714349616',
        'msg' => 'hggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg'       
        );


$data2 = http_build_query($data);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data2); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $reffer);
```

note: in the array must be all post data.